# Selenium ChromeDriver is getting timed out after google profile is loaded

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I wanted to load the chromedriver with default profile of chrome. I used the below code to do that.

```
var options=new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data");
var drivers=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

After I initiate the driver instance, the browser will be loaded with my profile.But soon after that the driver is getting timedout. I'm not able to proceed with further steps.

Can anyone help me with fixing this issue?
I am using c#.net as my scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the default profile while the one already running in background, please change the profile name under this directory. 
Like change `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

Copy the contents from User Data into another folder and rename to whatever name you want to. Then give this path as `--user-data` arguments.

Orelse another way is close the default chrome profile running in background and execute it.

Comment: This also did not work. After chrome is loded with default profile thr driver is geting timed out

Comment: Have you tried adding other arguments like `--start-maximized`.

Comment: Nope i did not try this. This looks like it would maximize the browser thats all right?

Comment: yeah it would only do that. But would let us know if the control is passed or not. Anyways, i did try to copy and rename the folder and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I copied my user data folder and called it user data_selenium and passed that to the --user-data option and it worked perfectly! Thanks